# How to detect which graphics adapter has monitors connected

Tags: display, adapter

We have an issue with some Dell Wyse thin clients running W10 2019. The devices are fitted with an onboard Intel UHD 605 display adapter with full size display port outputs and an AMD Radeon E9173 with mini DP outputs. Most have their monitors connected to the dedicated AMD display adapter but some are cabled to the onboard display adapter. The adapters have different

The issue is that when using the AMD card a 3rd "ghost" monitor appears in display settings (which the user has no access to). Disabling the Intel adapter fixes the issue and I can easily do this with powershell, however I need to know which machines have monitors connected to the  Intel and which to the AMD.

Looking in Windows Advanced display settings it says "Display 3: " (with no model) and shows it is connected to the intel 605. whereas Display 1 & 2 show the monitor model and that they are connected to the AMD card. I need a way to programmatically get this info. I have hunted through wmi and registry without success. Any ideas please???